# PHP using sleep to save database overload

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a WordPress plugin that needs to a number of posts and 20 post meta for each.

It was running fine until the posts count became large (5000+), the database started to fail and server was down.

I was wondering, will PHP `sleep` function help in this? Or what's better?

I was thinking (dummy example):

```
$i = 0;
foreach ( $posts_to_insert as $post ) {
    if ( $i == 100 ) sleep(3);
     heavy_function();
    $i++;
}
```

This function will run in a cron job, so no problem of using sleep with `ignore_user_abort` I think? Will this help MySQL in my situation?

Comment: What is overloading? The webserver or the MySQL server? With sleep you keep an open connection... so not sure if that would improve that much. You beter implement an 'offset' function, on which case you refresh the page with the new offset after x seconds. That way all the connections are cleared and restarted after x seconds.

Comment: The MySQL server is the one that's overloading. Yes I thought of the offset idea but thought that sleep would be more easy for a cron.

Comment: If it's the MySQL server than it should work. Although I think MySQL will need some 'more' time to get back on track than 3 seconds. But it depends on the queries you run in "heavy_function". Have you checked MySQL slow query log?

Comment: Yes, but I think the offset way is more safe to use, don't you think?

Comment: Yes, you can manually set offset by splitting it in 3 or 4 different cron jobs. I don't believe cron-jobs respond well to javascript redirects ;).